# Erro pagamento recorrente PagSeguro

Tags: php

Estou com um problema com a API do Pag Seguro no método /pre-approvals ele sempre me retorna que falta parâmetros mas estou enviando sim os parâmetros que a documentação pede. segui o passo a passo da documentação e mesmo assim nada.

```
$data['plan'] = 'CEC9F172-DDDD-DACD-D408-EF866A920B11';
    $data['sender.name'] = $dados['nome'];
    $data['sender.email'] = $dados['email'];
    $data['sender.hash'] = $dados['hash_comprador'];
    $data['sender.phone.number'] = str_replace("-", "", substr($dados["telefone"], 5));
    $data['senderPhone'] = str_replace("-", "", substr($dados["telefone"], 5));
    $data['sender.phone.areaCode'] = substr($dados["telefone"], 1, 2);
    $data['senderAreaCode'] = (int) substr($dados["telefone"], 1, 2);

    $data['sender.address.street'] = $dados['rua'];
    $data['sender.address.number'] = $dados['numero'];
    // $data['senderAddressComplement'] = $dados['nome'];
    $data['sender.address.district'] = $dados['bairro'];
    $data['sender.address.city'] = $dados['cidade'];
    $data['sender.address.state'] = $dados['uf'];
    $data['sender.address.country'] = 'BRA';
    $data['sender.address.postalCode'] = str_replace("-", "", $dados["cep"]);
    // $data['senderDocumentsType'] = $dados['nome'];
    // $data['senderDocumentsValue'] = $dados['nome'];
    $data['paymentMethod.type'] = 'creditCard';
    $data['paymentMethod.creditCard.token'] = $dados['card_token'];
    $data['paymentMethod.creditCard.holder.name'] = $dados['nome'];
    $data['paymentMethod.creditCard.holder.birthDate'] = $dados['nascimento'];

    $data = http_build_query($data);

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1',
                                        'Accept: application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+xml;charset=ISO-8859-1'
                                        ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $xml = curl_exec($curl);
```

No código acima, recupero os dados enviador do formulário, a documentação é bem confusa encontrei algumas com o envio dessa forma 'senderPhone' e outras com o envio dessa forma 'sender.phone.number', estou enviando o e-mail e token, já estou conseguindo fazer pagamento único via boleto e cartão, mas o pagamento recorrente sempre me retorna erros como:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu formulário HTML estou enviando todas as informações requeridas, depurei o código e estou realmente enviando tudo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor, se ficou confuso desculpem, mas estou desesperado!

Comment: Sugiro que de uma olhada no PagSeguro-PHP-SDK, fornecida pelo PagSeguro no link https://github.com/pagseguro/pagseguro-php-sdk. Eles fornecem um sdk completo para a integração, acho que ajuda em muito na integração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fala Mateus blz?

Aparentemente o erro está nos dados que você está enviando, só *debugando* para ver o que pode ser ao certo. Porém, fizemos uma integração com o *Pagseguro* recentemente e utilizamos o seguinte código:

```
$pagURL = 'https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/';
        $notificationCode = 'your-notification-code';
        $mail = 'your-email';
        $token = 'your-token';

        $url = $pagURL . "pre-approvals"
            . $notificationCode 
            . "?email=" . $mail 
            . "&token=" . $token;

        $data = Json::encode(array(
            "plan" => "*********",
            "reference" => "*********",
            "sender" => array(
                "name" => "*********",
                "email" => "*********",
                "hash" => "*********",
                "phone" => array(
                    "areaCode" => "*********",
                    "number" => "*********"
                ),
                "address" => array(
                    "street" => "*********",
                    "number" => "*********",
                    "complement" => "*********",
                    "district" => "*********",
                    "city" => "*********",
                    "state" => "*********",
                    "country" => "BRA",
                    "postalCode" => "*********",
                ),
                "documents" => array(array(
                    "type" => "CPF",
                    "value" => "*********",
                ))
            ),
            "paymentMethod" => array(
                "type" => "CREDITCARD",
                "creditCard" => array(
                    "token" => "*********",
                    "holder" => array(
                        "name" => "*********",
                        "birthDate" => "*********",
                        "documents" => array(array(
                            "type" => "CPF",
                            "value" => "*********",
                        )),
                        "phone" => array(
                            "areaCode" => "*********",
                            "number" => "*********",
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ));

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1','Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1'),
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
        ));

        try
        {
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $response = Json::decode($response);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            throw $e;
        }
```

A classe Json pode encontrar aqui: [Json.php](https://gist.github.com/jhonsore/30ba75bfc072e31930bc8fc54e497b72)

Espero que possa ajudar em algo.

Comment: Muito obrigado Jhonsore, funcionou perfeitamente enviando os parâmetros dessa forma!